# Show the set $S=\{(x,0): a <x < b\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not open

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I'm working through *Shifrin's Multivariable Mathemtics* and I'm working on an example from the book:

**Claim:** the set $S=\{(x,0): a <x < b\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not open.

The only concept I have to this point is a subset, $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, is open if for every $\textbf{a} \in U$ there is some ball centered at $\textbf{a}$ that is completely contained in $U$; that is, there is $\delta >0$ so that $B(\textbf{a}, \delta) \subset U$.

I understand why it is not open and the picture of the object also illustrated this. Essentially the idea being that any ball drawn around a point in $S$, for example $B(\textbf{a}, \delta)$ will contain points whose $y$ component will not be $y = 0$.  But I was trying to construct a formal argument using what I have learned up to this point, which  in terms of multivariable objects is not much. Can I do it using anything simplistic? Because any idea I attempt I'm running into the trouble of stating the idea above.

Comment: $S$ could be an open interval considered

Comment: Actually, I'm not really sure I see where you are having trouble with your argument.  It's quite correct and fairly formal.  All you really need to do demonstrate the point in $B(a,\delta)$ whose $y$ component is not $0$.  If $a=(x_1, 0)$ then you just need to come up with a point $b = (x_2, y_2)$ where $y_2\ne 0$ and $d(a,b)=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-0)^2} < \delta$.  That's not hard and an *aha* insight might be to realize $x_2$ is allowed to equal $x_1$. But even if you don't get that saying $y_2<\sqrt{\delta^2-(x_2-x_1)^2}: |x_2-x_1|< \delta$ will have easy to find solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any $a<x<b$. Then $\xi=(x,0)\in S$. Now take any $\delta>0$ and we will show that the ball $B(\xi,\delta)$ is not contained in $S$. Indeed, the point $(x,\frac{\delta}{2})$ belongs to this ball, but it is not in $S$. It belongs to the ball because:

$||(x,0)-(x,\frac{\delta}{2})||=||(0,\frac{\delta}{2})||=\frac{\delta}{2}<\delta$

So the set is not just not open, but even more so - it doesn't have **any** interior points.

Comment: Ah that's the idea I was missing! Having a point in the ball, but not in the set. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: $S$ could be an open inteval if considered as a subset of $\mathbb R$ but as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, no point of $S$ can be interior because the open set of $\mathbb R^2$ are union of open balls (bidimensional ones).

Answer (score 2):

You describe it fairly correctly.  TO do it formally.

Let $P\in S$.  Then $P = (w,0)$ for some real $w: a <x < b$.

Consider any radius $r > 0$ and consider the open ball $B_r(P)$.

Let $Q = (w,\frac 12 r)\in \mathbb R^2$.  We can easily show that $Q\in B_r(P)$ (because $d(P,Q) = \sqrt{(w-w)^2 +(\frac 12r-0)^2} = \frac 12r < r$)  and we can easily see that $Q \not \in S$ (because $Q = (w, \frac 12r)$ and $\frac 12r \ne 0$).

This is true for *any* open ball around $P$ of any radius, so there is no open ball around $P$ completely contained is $S$ so $P$ is not an interior point of $S$.  So $S$ contains a point that is not an interior point (indeed *none* of the points of $S$ are interior points) so $S$ is not open.